# Javascript in Office

Tags: vba, ms-office, vsto, office-js

I am trying to understand how to develop add-ins/macros in JS for Office, do I need VSTO for it or does it run from Office somewhere?

I did understood that Microsoft is making the first steps toward replacing VBa with JS and impemented an API to develop macros in Office.Js simmilar to the one Google has for it's Docs. But where can I find a development enviroment for Office.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new web-based add-ins are basically a web application executed in the context of the Office application, either on the Desktop (by embedding a browser, IE11 at the moment) or in the browser (Office Online) where everything is web-based already.

The add-in can be hosted on any web resource you like. You just need to specify a source location URI.

Settings and metadata of the add-in are defined in a manifest file. The article [Office Add-ins platform overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins) describes it very well.

[image: Basic structure of a web-based Office add-in]

Development can be done in any editor or IDE suitable for coding web apps. There is no <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> VBA IDE anymore, but you may try the [Script Lab add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/), a Microsoft Garage project that allows you to try out some code directly in Office and share code snippets. It includes a great collection of sample code too.

[image: The Script Lab add-in inside Excel]

Answer (score 0):

The new WebApplications are hosted on a Webserver. You can develop Office Apps with Visual Studio.
Here is a good course for developing Office Apps including an overview of the Javascript Office API:
https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/introduction-to-office-365-development-8329